# How to calculate Median of a table field in the Dissolve Tool of ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, dissolve

The Dissolve Tool of ArcGIS 10.0 has some statistical parameters as a type of calculation  new values of each field in a process of dissolving of identical parameters . It has SUM, MAX, MIN, RANGE, STD and a bit more Statistical types , but it doesn’t have MEDIAN.

It’s very  strange, why it doesn’t have  Median (and some others important statistical parameters). But maybe it’s possible to “turn on” calculation  “Median” in the Dissolve Tool, or solve this task in some other way?

Comment: Here is a good post of a python script implementation for calculating median: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1729&t=299704

Comment: perhaps calculate the median prior to dissolve with 'summary statistics' and then join and calculate before or after dissolve to apply the values to the original table.

Comment: It seems that Summary Statistics Tool doesn't have Median as well. It has the same statistical types as Dissolve Tool.

Comment: Thank you, ew_gis, I'll see this script. Just strange, why they don't give this option? If they give many types of Statistic, why didn't include all basic types?

Comment: @evv_gis the hyperlink you mention no longer works.  Can you repost it again please?  Has anyone else come up with a solution?